# Anyone else having Provisioning Profile Problems in iOS?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

Since the Apple Developer Site outage, we are unable to add new devices to a new or existing provisioning profile and have the app install without error to those new devices. Devices added before the recent outage work just fine with new and existing profiles, but any device added since about Saturday August 3 2013 fails, from the same file!

We have built new profiles and modified existing ones without luck. I have submitted a bug to Apple, but no response.

We distribute through TestFlight to testers, and the install works great on old devices prior to that date. However, devices added since, download the file and seem to fail at the point where the "install" takes place (ie, signature check and decryption.)

TestFlight correctly recognizes the new (and all old) devices as being added to the profile, and the installs show up properly in TestFlight on all devices as available.

My guess is that keys are being corrupted when new devices are being added to the portal.

I am looking to see if anyone else has had this problem, and if they have any kind of workaround for the issue? I have tried new profiles, new builds, new devices! Nothing works

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some hours ago, I added a new device and created a new Ad Hoc Distribution profile to test an app on a non-dev device. The app installed and runs fine. But I don't use TestFlight.

Comment: I can add and distribute through Ad Hoc just fine as well. I'd say TestFlight would be the one to look into.

Comment: So maybe the problem is with Development certificates (since we are distributing to other developers) and not using Ad-Hoc. I will test that theory. However, those always worked before. Thanks

Comment: But I do need to be clear here. It has to be distributed to a device you JUST added to your profile. It cannot have existed in the Portal before Saturday. CaptJack and Nero, is that the case for both of you? It is ONLY to newly added devices since Saturday. Devices already in the portal and profile work just fine BTW

Comment: Yep. As I said: New device, new Ad Hoc Distribution profile and the app runs on said newly added device; but without TestFlight. Basically I followed [this guide from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) except for "distributing" the app over the air to the test-device.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same as Nero. New app, new device, new certificate, new Provisioning Profile, Ad Hoc Distribution, all today.

Comment: I added a new device just before the outage, it worked, then when Profiles came back up I added another device, that worked but the first stopped working - I think because Apple went to a backup from before I added the first device (it was about 12 hours before the outage) and the first device wasn't in the list any more. So I added the first device again and both work (AdHoc, via TestFlight).

Comment: Thank to both of you. Back to the drawing board. Trying now with AdHoc instead of developer profiles. Apple responded and said they were "aware of a problem". Maybe only hits some. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, created a new AdHoc provisioning profile with the exact same results: Old devices work fine, new devices fail from the same file. I can't imagine how TestFlight could be the culprit here. We are trying manual install next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this problem just "went away." Apple did say they were having some problems, but the problem went away before I touched the Apple developer portal again, so not so sure.

TestFlight said they made no changes, but more research and we discovered as issue which I believe wad theirs:

Old devices still allowed the install, because they still contained old provisioning profiles from the same company (us) that covered more than one build. So any of those profiles already on the device, and the install worked fine.

New installs were not installing the provisioning profile correctly for some reason, so the installs failed because there were no old profiles. In some cases, they appeared to install an old profile that did not have the new keys, and that failed too.

We discovered that by installing a new profile by hand to new devices, all apps installed fine from TestFlight. As of last Monday though, the profiles were being properly installed again by TestFlight.

TestFlight says they changed nothing. I'm not so sure. but this problem has disappeared for the time being.

Thanks for all the answers.